# how to change camera view to focus more then one markers

Tags: android, google-maps

i am developing an android application for parking cars, and i have draw path b/w the current position and park place. But how can i set camera view so that both the points should be focused. ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can mark my answer below if it helped :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this with `latLng_1` and `latLng_2` as `LatLng` objects of the two markers.

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            builder.include(latLng_1);
            builder.include(latLng_2);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
                    builder.build(), 25, 25, 0));
```